# $\mathbb{P}^1$ a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

This question comes from Chapter 5 of [Gathmann's notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014.pdf): how is $\mathbb{P}^1$ a variety? I know we have to show the diagonal $\{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{P}^1\} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is closed, I'm just not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Look up [Segre embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding). It gives, among other things, a copy of $\Bbb{P}^1\times\Bbb{P}^1$ inside $\Bbb{P}^3$. It is highly likely that somebody has elaborated on it on this site already.

Comment: I think if you want to use only what Gathmann has taught in the preceeding chapters, you can proceed as follows: Let $U_1, U_2$, each isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$, be affine varieties that can be glued together to cover $\mathbb{P}^1$. Let $V_1, V_2$ be another pair of affine varieties with the same property. Then we know the topology for $U_i \times V_i$, it is just the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$. Then $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ can be obtained by gluing together the four sets $U_i \times V_i$, and Gathmann has also defined the ...

Comment: ...topology that you get from gluing stuff together (a subset of the glued surface is open iff the preimages under all the inclusion maps are open i think). So we do have way to get the topology on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. However, it seems to me like its going to be a huge mess to actually show that the diagonal is closed...

Comment: Maybe its not so bad after all? For e.g. one of the things (depending on how you glue the $U_i$ and $V_i$) you want to show is that $\{ (x, 1/x) : x \in \mathbb{A}^1 \}$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$, but this is clear i think?

Answer (score 3):

Showing that the diagonal is closed in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is a step in showing that $\mathbb{P}^1$ itself is a variety, not that the product is a variety. Once you've shown that $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a variety, then show that the product of any two varieties is again a variety.

If your question is why $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a variety to begin with, can you think of a nice choice of affine open sets covering $\mathbb{P}^1$ on which you could check this?